# NiFi - Thread still runs after stopping processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm developing a publish subscribe processor with Eclipse Milo for Apache NiFi.
I have a service that handles most of the interaction with Eclipse Milo and the server and a controller that essentially just calls the service's functions.
The subscribing to nodes on the OPCUA server works fine, but I can't think of a good way to terminate the subscription, e.g. when I stop the processor.
The subscription, which "lives" in the service, survives the service getting disabled, as well as the controller being disabled/stopped. That means that the @OnStopped & @OnUnscheduled methods that I defined never get called, likely because the subscription never gets terminated. So I can't use these two methods. 
I know that I can terminate threads in NiFi 1.7+, but I don't think that's a good way to handle this and also I'm still using 1.2.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version, some problems with the way processors finish were fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Did updating the latest version work, if so, which version is it?

Comment: I realized that I didn't actually report back. Sorry for that. Yes upgrading to the latest version fixed my issue.